# How to exclude path on the deployment in PhpStorm from .gitignore

Tags: deployment, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I always need to exclude all the path defined in the `.gitignore` file when I synchronize the server with the deployment feature of *PhpStorm*.

There is a way to copy these path and exclude them without manually exclude them one by one?

I'm searching like a configuration file or somewhere to put a list of directory and files like in the `.gitignore` file

Comment: There is no such functionality in PhpStorm (maybe via 3rd party plugin). Thing is: quite often you need to have some files/folders ignored in VCS but still be able to participate in deployment in both ways (e.g. some media files/content generated by users; some other server-side generated content that may be required locally (e.g. run-time config/caches) for debugging etc.) -- such *automatic exclusion* will make such use case not working.

Comment: I such a case you can manually add these specific folder later if really needed. Anyways it does not have to be from the `.gitignore` file. I just need a way to copy and paste a list of excluded folder without exclude them manually one by one.

Comment: The best thing **I** can offer is to edit config file with deployment settings manually (it's a XML file -- easy to manipulate or even automate) while project is closed in IDE -- `.idea/deployment.xml`. This is, of course, if this deployment entry is marked as project-specific (visible for this project only). Otherwise it has to be done on IDE-wide config level (which is more complicated -- easier to make mistake). **P.S.** consider using `@username` otherwise user will not be notified about new comment and may miss it.